# Query that creates 1000 rows in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query to generates 1000 rows, I have a table called CCHOMEWORK with 2 columns, ID integer (PK) and StudentID varchar which contains the value for all the 1000 rows.

I tried this, but I keep getting errors and does not work

```
SET @MyCounter = 1

WHILE @MyCounter < 1000

BEGIN

INSERT INTO CCHOMEWORK
    (ID)
VALUES
    @MyCounter)

    set @MyCounter = @MyCounter + 1;

END
```

Comment: Your code looks like SQL Server code.  Are you sure you are using Oracle?

Comment: Yes, I am using oracle SQL connected with amazon, I found this code searching online, so it is possible it's all wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will create 1000 rows:

```
SELECT LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000
```

You can include it in your insert with:

```
INSERT INTO CCHOMEWORK (ID)
SELECT LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000
```

However, if you want to insert multiple sequential IDs you might be better using a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE CCHOMEWORK__ID__SEQ
/
```

Then:

```
INSERT INTO CCHOMEWORK (ID)
SELECT CC_HOMEWORK__ID__SEQ.NEXTVAL
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000;
```

Or:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 1000 LOOP
    INSERT INTO CCHOMEWORK (ID) VALUES ( CC_HOMEWORK__ID__SEQ.NEXTVAL );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks, but then how can I use those rows from dual and copy it into my table?

Comment: @roberto.sannazzaro . . . Use a CTE or `create table as`.

Comment: @roberto.sannazzaro I was just updating the answer to include that... done now.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for Oracle database (using PL/SQL):

```
DECLARE 
    MyCounter NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN MyCounter> 1000;
        INSERT INTO CCHOMEWORK (ID)
        VALUES(MyCounter);
        MyCounter := MyCounter+1;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```